# How to upsert documents with dynamic update values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a query that varies the update value according to the document.

Such as,
given schema is **Carts**

finding many documents with array, suppose

```
user: { $in: [userid_1,userid_2,userid_3]}
```

And some common field to upsert - **items: ['item']**

Upserted documents should result like following; if not found user, it will create

```
{user:userid_1,items: ['item']}
{user:userid_2,items: ['item']}
{user:userid_3,items: ['item']}
```

On some research, found the **Bulk** operator, but I am unable to make use of it.

**Notes:**

'for loops' would make it easier, but it will be slower, thus just requiring the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a bulk operation for this:

```
const cartsBulk = cartsModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (const userid of [userid_1,userid_2,userid_3]) {
  cartsBulk.find({user: {$in: [userid_1,userid_2,userid_3]}).upsert().update({$set:{items: ["item"]}});
}
await cartsBulk.execute()
```

Comment: Is for loop necessary here? could you please add more details of the operation?

Comment: It will be resolved into one query. Notice the execution is only once, after the for loop.