# Multiple updateOne() is time consuming in MongoDB. What is the way around that?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My project is in MongoDB and NodeJS. I have an array of objects which can contain thousands of objects and it looks like the following -

```
busData = [
  {
    fromDate: "2023-05-04",
    busNumber: "5680",
    passRevenue: 23
  },
  {
    fromDate: "2023-05-04",
    busNumber: "5689",
    passRevenue: 30
  }
]
```

I need to update the BusDayWise collection of MongoDB. The condition for the update is I need to match the document by filter - {busNumber, fromDate}, and then add the above busData.passRevenue value to the existing one. If the matched document does not have a field of passRevenue, it should simply set the passRevenue value with the above busData.passRevenue. The issue is I am using multiple findOneAndUpdate which is taking a huge amount of time. Is there a way to reduce the database calls? Please look at the code below for reference -

```
const updatePassRevenue = async ({ busDayWiseAggrt}) => {

  for(let bd = 0; bd < busDayWiseAggrt.data.length; bd++) {
    let busData = busDayWiseAggrt.data[bd];
    let res = await BusDayWise.findOne(
      {
        fromDate: busData.fromDate,
        busNumber: busData.busNumber,
        metadata: { $exists: false }
      }
    );
    if(res.passRevenue) {
      await BusDayWise.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: res._id },
        { $inc: { passRevenue: busData.passRevenue } }
      )
    }
    else {
      await BusDayWise.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: res._id },
        { $set: { passRevenue: busData.passRevenue } }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a bulk update. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73157154/how-to-upsert-documents-with-dynamic-update-values-in-mongodb)